# Help with basic php and xml needed

Tags: php, xml, gd

I'm really new to xml, with this being my first dip into it.

I'm trying to add some text to an image using php and xml.

I keep getting the following error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/a8744502/public_html/userbar.php on line 18**

Below is my code.

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( "http://phogue.net/feed/". LIBXML_DTDLOAD );

$procon = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "procon" );

$packages = $procon->getElementsByTagName( "package" );
$value = 0;

foreach($packages as $package)
{
  $downloadsA = $package->getElementsByTagName( "downloads" );
  $downloads = $downloadsA->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $value = $downloads + $value
}                                           
$font  = "visitor1.tff";
$font  = 4;
$im = ImageCreateFromjpeg("procon_plugindeveloper.jpg");
$x = 360;
$y = 0;
$background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagestring ($im, $font, $x, $y,  $value, $text_color);
imagejpeg ($im);
?>
```

The xml file is of the form

```
<procon>
-<packages>
--<package>
---<downloads>
---</doanloads>
--</package>

--<package>
---<downloads>
---</doanloads>
--</package>

--<package>
---<downloads>
---</doanloads>
--</package>


-</packages>
</procon>
```

The idea is that it should print out the sum of all the downloads tags that are contained in .

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $value = $downloads + $value
}
```

missing a `;`

can't say if that'll make it work though.

also you probably mean `$value .= $downloads + $value;` to add on top of the $value variable, else it will just get overwritten each iteration

**edit:**

you can also just do:

`$value += $download; //$value equals $value + $download`

to really confuse you !

Comment: ah dang it.. thats what I get for working on some VB code for the past few hours :p..

Comment: Can you explain what the .= does please?

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP. Basically saying add the result of the right hand equation to the current value of `$value`; sort of a running total rather than overwriting it each time. Appends would be a better word, more @ http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: so I should just have $value .= $downloads  or is the trailing $value still needed?

Comment: Cool.. I can see what its doing.. I'm just getting a broken image icon now :s   Can you see anything else wrong with my code?

Comment: `$value.=$downloads` would literally concat the two variables, e.g `$value=1;$downloads=2; $value.=$downloads;` produces `12` not 3. no equation is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Missing a ; on the last line of your `foreach`. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP error, nothing to do with XML. This line:

```
$value = $downloads + $value
```

needs a semicolon at the end...